# How can I forward email service email to a different address?

Tags: apex-email-service

I will be having email alerts sent to clients and I want their replies to go to an Email Service address. But I can't simply make that long address the "From" address because that must be an org-wide approved email address, which you cannot do with an email service address.

So, it's been suggested to me to use an org-wide approved address (sales@company.com etc) and simply set up that email account to automatically forward all of its mail to the long email service address. However, I can't use the long email service address as a destination address in the forwarding process either. Gmail needs to send a verification to whatever email will be used and I cannot perform an approval for the email address, or at least I don't know how to.

How can I accomplish this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have done in the past for an email service address is capture the email requesting verification and forward it to a real address so the link can be clicked to verify. Then you can use the long address as a forwarding

You can modify the below code as appropriate

```
global class email_Handler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

        global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

            Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
            String attachment_body;

            //Reroute Verification Email
            if(email.plainTextBody.contains('We have received the following request to add this')){
                sendVerificationEmail(email, 'xxxxx');
                return result;
            }
        }

        private void sendVerificationEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, String toAddress){


            Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {toAddress};


            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Test');

            mail.setSubject('Test');
            mail.setPlainTextBody(email.plainTextBody);
            mail.setHtmlBody(email.htmlBody);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });



        }

    }
```

Comment: i love it! almost like a judo move on SFDC itself

Comment: ha ! Nice one @Eric. Thanks a bunch !

Comment: @Eric - I keep getting an error : expecting a semi-colon, found '(' on line 14 which is the line starting with "private void sendVerification...". I've looked at it and I don't see the problem. I must be overlooking something obvious. Any suggestions....?

Comment: @Zoom_v - Yea, forgot a bracket. Updated

Comment: Eric, I tried your code but I am still not getting the verification email. I even tried removing the `if(email.plainTextBody.contains('We have received the following request to add this')){` condition so that in any case I will get the email but had no luck either. However if I manually send an email to the long email service address I am receiving the email. Any clue what I could be missing here?